# Is it possible to obtain number of prepared statements a connection holds?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, connections, prepared-statement, session

I have a heavy loaded application that holds connections persistently (it creates them on start and never releases).

During the lifetime it creates and (re)uses prepared statements, which are stored in an LRU structure (so the least used are eventually released).

And the question is: is it possible to obtain the number and other statistics of prepared statements for a given connection?

There is nothing relevant on http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/monitoring-stats.html so not sure if there are other interfaces to access postgresql stats.

**UPD**: I probably was not clear enough: I need to obtain information using the normal DBA connection, since I cannot run arbitrary queries from the production software. For that very reason the `pg_prepared_statements` solution would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view prepared statements with the [`pg_prepared_statements`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-prepared-statements.html) view. Query this view to get a count.

Comment: "The pg_prepared_statements view displays all the prepared statements that are available in the **current session**" --- and that's the problem: I cannot run arbitrary queries in the real production connections.

Comment: Seems like your other answer on stackoverflow would satisfy me :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/12160161/251311

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pg_prepared_statements view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-prepared-statements.html) to show all the prepared statements in the current session. *Prepared statements are deleted after logout:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_prepared_statements;
```

And, you can use [count()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) to show the number of all the prepared statements in the current session:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM pg_prepared_statements;
```

Comment: You have not read the question entirely have you?